# pyautogui locateAllOnScreen how do i remove it from the list?

Tags: python, pyautogui

i'm new on python and i'm trying to do bot for game. The aim of the game is when the mouse stay over the box, color becomes apparent. Click on the box until the color turns green.The code works, but it clicks on each box once and even after the boxes turn green, it comes back to that box and checks it. It wastes a lot of time as there are 30+ boxes in the game. what I want is to come to the box once and click until it turns green, then remove that box from the list of boxes. how can I do that ?

```
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard
import time
import pydirectinput

if pg.locateOnScreen('box.png', confidence=0.9):
    boxs = pg.locateAllOnScreen('box.png', confidence=0.9)
    for box in boxs:
        pg.moveTo(box)
        time.sleep(.2)
        if pg.locateOnScreen('red', confidence=0.95) or pg.locateOnScreen('orange',
                                                                             confidence=0.95) or pg.locateOnScreen(
                'blue', confidence=0.95) or pg.locateOnScreen('white', confidence=0.95) or pg.locateOnScreen(
                'brown', confidence=0.95) or pg.locateOnScreen('black', confidence=0.95):
            pg.mouseDown()
            pg.mouseUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "or" when you want to use something along the lines of "if not green then click until green"

Right now the codes saying if its any one of these colors click once and move on